# How do I access data from Form.Item?

Tags: antd

```
export function URLInput() {  
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col span={24}>
        <FloatLabel label="URL" name="url" labelValue={value}>
          <Form.Item
            hasFeedback
            name="url"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                min: 5,
                type: "url",
                whitespace: true,
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input
              name="url"
              onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Item>
        </FloatLabel>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

I currently have this Form.Item setup.

If there is already a value in url set in the form's `initialValues`, the Form.Item will magically populate the input field with the value.

However, I want to be able to access this value too so that I can initialize `value` in

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("I want to initialize the value here without introducing a props");
```

How do I do this?

Edit:
The `<URLInput>` component is actually used inside of a `<Form>` like this:

```
<Form
      form={form}
      onFinish={handleFormSubmit}
      initialValues={{ content: content}}
    >
    <URLInput/>
</Form>
```

Comment: You can't use `Form.Item` component outside of a parent `Form` component. Please modify the CodeSanbox link below to generate a minimal working a example of your component, so I may provide additional feedback.

https://codesandbox.io/s/malformed-form-item-component-uwdb7

Comment: Edited the post. It wasn't obvious in my initial question, but the `Form.Item` component is actually being used inside the `Form` component

Comment: I understand. Thank you. Try my suggestions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `form` to `URLInput` as a prop, then inside `URLInput` you can access the initialValue `url` by invoking the following `form.getFieldValue('url')`.

Please see working CodeSandbox example below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/antdform-accessing-formvalues-in-child-formitem-component-uwdb7

Happy coding!